# adjust the size of boxplot so that label become clear

Tags: python

I am plotting the box plot graph but the x-axis labels are overlapping to each other and graph is looking messy. I want to increase the width of graph so that labels become clear, but am unsure what methods to use. My code looks like:

```
df2=Restaurant.boxplot(by ='Item', column =['Profit'], grid = True)
df2.plot(kind='box', figsize=(20,15))
plt.savefig('finalBoxPlot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

And the resulting graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KhNo.png)

Comment: Maybe you could tilt the text at an angle so the lines of text don't intersect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK just rotating the labels instead of adjusting plot size you would accomplish this with:

```
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center')
```

Where `ax` was defined earlier in my code as

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1) # whatever shape
```

But I'm not sure if this would work without plotting to an `ax`. You could always run

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15)) # this is how I adjust figure sizes too
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
```

To create a single `ax` on your plot, making the above method viable, and then you would plot your information with `ax.plot()` instead of `plt.plot()` for instance.

I am not sure how applicable this is with `pandas` dataframes though, since I haven't really worked with them.